# How to align phpdoc comments in vim

Tags: vim, code-formatting

Is there a easy way to align phpdoc comment blocks in vim?

I want

```
/**
 * Call an API method.
 * @param string $method The API method to call, e.g. 'lists/list'
 * @param array $args An array of arguments to pass to the method. Will be json-encoded for you.
 * @return array Associative array of json decoded API response.
 */
```

to be formatted as

```
/**
 * Call an API method.
 * @param  string $method The API method to call, e.g. 'lists/list'
 * @param  array  $args   An array of arguments to pass to the method. Will be json-encoded for you.
 * @return array          Associative array of json decoded API response.
 */
```

Formatting the line that contains @return may be tough, because it doesn't contain the third column. So even if I can come up with a way to align only the lines that contain @param that would be great.

**Edit**:

I have already tried the [tabular addon](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular), but that doesn't work since in the above case, we can't use space as the delimeter.

**Edit 2**:

This is the second usecase for which @PeterRincker answer is failing

```
/**
 * Call an API method.
 * @since 1.7
 * @param string $method The API method to call, e.g. 'lists/list'
 * @param array $args An array of arguments to pass to the method. Will be json-encoded for you.
 * @return array Associative array of json decoded API response.
 */
```

It becomes

```
/**
 * Call an API method.
 * @since  1      .7
 * @param  string $method The API method to call, e.g. 'lists/list'
 * @param  array  $args   An array of arguments to pass to the method. Will be json-encoded for you.
 * @return array          Associative array of json decoded API response.
 */
```

Comment: Tabular vim plugin should do that.

Comment: @Amit I already tried the tabular plugin, but it won't for this case, because we can't use space as the delimiter.

Comment: It can align on a regex also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure this could be simplified but it worked for your example case:

```
:Tabularize/@\w\+\s\+\zs\S\+\|\%(@\w\+.*\)\@<=\u.*/
```

Overview

The key to this is to pick good deliminators to split on because we want to align the `@return` line as well as the `@param` lines. Use Tabularize to split on the start of the WORD after an `@`-word and the first uppercase letter.

Explanation

- `\|` creates a branches in a regex pattern. This means we can split on both deliminators
- `@\w\+` matches `@` followed by a word. e.g. `@param`
- `\zs` set the start of the match
- `@\w\+\s\+\zs\S\+` match an `@`-word followed by a WORD and set the start of the match a the start of the WORD
- `\u` match an uppercase letter
- `\u.*` match the uppercase letter followed the rest of the line to prevent more splits
- `\%(...\)` a non-capturing group
- `\@<=` is vim's positive look behind. `\(foo\)\@<=bar` matches `bar` after `foo` in `foobar`
- `\%(@\w\+.*\)\@<=\u` match an uppercase letter that follows an `@`-word

Common Tabular alignment idioms

- use `\zs` to set the start of a match
- end with `.*` to consume the rest of the line and prevent more splitting

For more help see:

```
:h :Tabularize
:h /\|
:h /\S
:h WORD
:h /\zs
:h /\u
:h /\%(
:h /\@<=
```

Comment: This works for this usecase, but fails for other similar usecases. But I can use this as a base and then try to modify it for other usecases. Can you kindly explain me briefly what is happening here. Thanks.

Comment: @Sudar I have added an explanation. You may want to provide some of the sample text that fails

Comment: @PeterRincker Thanks for the explanation. It fails when we have a dot (.) in the text. I have updated the question with that usecase. I should have included it before itself. Sorry about it.

Comment: This answer was near perfect for me.  I did however change it as our doc blocks were not up to snuff and didn't start the comment of the param's with a capital letter.  Doing the following works for me and hopefully will help someone else. :Tabularize/@\w\+\s\+\zs\S\+\|\%(@\w\+.*\)\@<=\s\w.*/

Comment: This works fine for me, but how to mapping it the shortcut, I tried `vmap ta :Tabularize/@\w\+\s\+\zs\S\+\|\%(@\w\+.*\)\@<=\u.*/<CR>`, but it won't work

Comment: @chan You will need to replace `|` with `<bar>` as pipe symbols are used to separate Vim commands

Comment: I found it's won't work with camelcase parameter, `param string $shceduleName Schedule name` will become `param string  $shcedule Name Schedule name`

Comment: Chinese will be failure too